# Simple Android layout not behaving as expected

Tags: android

I want a layout like this (where the border represents the Android device's screen):

[image]

That is, I want, in a single column:

1. The title
2. Immediately under that, an image, scaled to just fit the width of the screen.
3. Immediately under that, the date and description.

The whole thing can be scrolled vertically if need  be (ie, if the image is really tall).

I'm trying a linear layout with the image's width/height set to "match_parent" and "wrap_content" respectively, but I'm getting this weird behavior where the image has massive, screen-filling margins above and below it, forcing the date and description past the bottom of the screen.

This is a very simple layout. What's the correct way to implement it?

My attempt looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/iotd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Show us your code that implements the layout.

Comment: Since you are not specifying a fixed "height" for the image if it is big, it will push all your items out of screen, try this, set the imageview height property to "250dp" and see what happens, if the img works as expected then you are safe to go for a scaleType

Comment: @MartinCazares Setting it to 250dp stops the vertical margins above and below it, but now it's too small. Using a scaletype made it the right size bu puts back in the vertical margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [`android:adjustViewBounds="true"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3aadjustViewBounds). Use it with `scaleType` you want.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Even without scaleType. So without adjustViewBounds, the bounding box for the ImageView stays the size of the original image?

Comment: `adjustViewBounds` forces Android to resize the `ImageView` to match the resized image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Title"
android:textSize="40sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/iotd" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: some wraps against matches, also set a scaletype to imgview

Comment: Note that `center` will not work if the image is too big (it will not scale down). In that case, `center_inside` would be better. If the image also needs to scale up, `fit_center` is the way to go. Also, please add a description to your answer so it's easier to use.

Comment: or set if to `fitXY` it really depends on his needs

Comment: `fitXY` can change the ratio of the image, which is almost always unwanted :)

Comment: Just sayin' that I have no clue what he wants so he has to figure it our his self :P

Answer (score 0):

Try setting scaleType for your imageview.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/iotd" />
```

For details of various scaleTypes, refer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

CenterCrop will scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Comment: Make sure to know which one you choose though. `centerCrop` will match both x and y axes, and crop off the rest, which is usually not wanted. This is a nice overview of the scaletypes: http://etcodehome.blogspot.nl/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Comment: I've tried all of the scaletypes and they always produce vertical margins. Why is that?

Comment: Well, are you sure that the image does not have transparent pixels on top and bottom?